# How To Fix This ?? >> incompatible with FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have a program using fragment, but i have a problem, when i including list view in my pager when one of item on sliding menu selected.

these the error :

on tabs adapter

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

```
public TabsPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
}

@Override
public FragmentActivity getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new SoloAttractionFragment();
    case 1:
        return new KaranganyarAttractionFragment();
    case 2:
        return new SukoharjoAttractionFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
```

}

the error in line :

public FragmentActivity getItem(int index) {

Multiple markers at this line
    - implements 
     android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem
    - The return type is incompatible with 
     FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem(int)
    - The return type is incompatible with 
     FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem(int)

please help me, thanks

the other class related :

public class SoloAttractionFragment extends FragmentActivity {

```
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
// XML node keys
public static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
public static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
public static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_attraction_solo);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new 
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        });
}
```

This is adapter for list view :

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(SoloAttractionFragment.KEY_TITLE));
    artist.setText(song.get(SoloAttractionFragment.KEY_ARTIST));
    duration.setText(song.get(SoloAttractionFragment.KEY_DURATION));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(SoloAttractionFragment.KEY_THUMB_URL), position, thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

}

Comment: your fragments need to extend Fragment NOT FragementActivity

Comment: before, i using fragment but in SoloAttractionFragment class, i have to extends activity too, so extends fragment and activity, so i change to be FragmentActivity. how to fix it, if i change like before, in SoloAttractionFragment class, what i have to change ?? @Akos Cz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return FragmentActivity from getItem(), because FragmentActivity is not a Fragment, but an Activity that can contain Fragments. getItem() must return a Fragment or ListFragment.

Comment: I understand, but how to create a class that contains the Activity can carry Fragment. so it does not become an error?

Comment: Only your main activity needs to extend "FragmentActivity", because is the one containing the fragments (it is the parent of the 3 fragments inside the pager) and needs to have access to FragmentManager necessary to interact with the 3 fragments. The other 3 classes, the ones returned by the FragmentStatePagerAdapter, should extend "Fragment". And the FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem() needs to return Fragment: "public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {...}", "public class SoloAttractionFragment extends Fragment {...}", "public Fragment getItem(int index) {...}".

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SoloAttractionFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```